# How can I generate CodeCoverage-Reports with Kover?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kover

I am trying out Kotlin Native with a tiny project on my system. At a certain point I wanted to get the Code-Coverage of my tests. IntelliJ offers the Option "Run with Coverage" which did not generate coverage reports.
After a little search I found [*kover*](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) which can provide CodeCoverage-Reports for Kotlin native.

Unfortunately I am unable make it working even with a minimal setup as the following.

*build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.6.1"
}

group = "me.user"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    macosX64()
    sourceSets {
        val macosX64Main by getting
        val macosX64Test by getting
    }
}
```

*Main.kt*

```kotlin
class Main{
    fun add(first : Int, second : Int) : Int{
        return 4;
    }
}
```

*MainTest.kt*

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class MainTest{
    @Test
    fun addTest(){
        assertEquals(Main().add(2,2), 4);
    }
}
```

I followed the description [*here*](https://lengrand.fr/kover-code-coverage-plugin-for-kotlin/) and the [*documentation*](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx-kover/). At the documentation it states, that after applying the plugin with

```
plugins {
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.6.1"
}
```

> Once you’ve applied Kover, you can run it without additional configuration.

Unfortunately neither running *allTests* nor running the *report*-Tasks generates CodeCoverage files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was a known [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover/issues/316) which should be fixed in a upcoming release.